# How the control is going from one switch case to another without break c#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Just started `C#` and I came to know you cannot go from one `switch` case to another if there is at least one statement. Error : `Control cannot fall through from one case  to another` .

Just for fun stuff I tried this out :

```
        char c = 'a';
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'a':
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
                goto JumpToNextCase;
            case 'b':
                 JumpToNextCase:
                Console.WriteLine("Kiddin me?");
                break;

        }
```

And this worked ! How can it be?Am I now not violating the rule of jumping from one case to other? Any satisfying answer?

Comment: You are not falling through here.  You are `goto`ing a label that happens to be in the following `case`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, the limitation is just to prevent something that in 99% of cases is an accident and a bug.

However, you don't even need a label to make it work, if you think you want it to work. **You can use `goto` to jump to different `case`!**

```
char c = 'a';
switch (c)
{
    case 'a':
        Console.WriteLine("yes");
        goto case 'b';
    case 'b':
        Console.WriteLine("Kiddin me?");
        break;
}
```

You can also jump to `default`. C# spec mentions that:

> **8.9.3 The goto statement** The goto statement transfers control to a statement that is marked by a label.
>
> ```
> goto-statement:
> goto   identifier   ;
> goto   case   constant-expression   ;
> goto   default   ;
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> The target of a `goto case` statement is the statement list in the immediately enclosing switch statement (§8.7.2), which contains a `case` label with the given constant value.
>
> (...)
>
> The target of a `goto default` statement is the statement list in the immediately enclosing switch statement (§8.7.2), which contains a `default` label.

Comment: Wow cool  `goto case 'b'` worked thanks, and for the specifications too!

Answer (score 8):

The error about falling through cases is a protection against accidents, not some fundamental limitation to the language. Previous languages like C let you fall through without warning or error, but - typically - this is a bug, and you've just forgotten the `break`. C# introduced the error to prevent these bugs.

There's nothing to stop you working around it, as indeed you have. However, you'd had to do it *deliberately*, rather than by accident, and so (hopefully) won't be introducing bugs by doing it.

Answer (score 2):

It worked because you used the `goto` statement.

`goto` redirects the program flow, ending the case. You can use `return` as well (instead of `break`) and it will compile just fine.

The compiler only complains when the case does not terminate in some way (falls through).

I'm sure you know this, but `goto` is pretty much never a good idea anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Fall through is not allowed mainly because a programmer could easily forget the `break;` and that would probably be a bug because they **never intended** to run the second `case` block.  In this case you are **explicitly asking** that another block be run, so it is clearly not something you did by accident.  **C# is simply forcing you to be more assertive about asking it to run the other case to ensure fall through doesn't happen by accident.**